# How to guarantee all requests are fulfilled asynchronously, and map the request url to the promise response in Node.js 10.x.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

I have several GET Requests that need to be made, and due to a Timeout limitation, they have to be run asynchronously and I need to guarantee all run. Also, when the result returns, I need to know to which URL it is referred.

The first part I've managed to solve, but I'm unable to map to the correct url. Here is the code:

```
urls = ['https://example-a.com', 'https://example-b.com', 'https://example-c.com']

Promise.all(promises.map(p => fetch(p.url))).then(function(res){
    var blobPromises = [];

    /* HERE I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHICH URL'S REQUEST WAS RETURNED */
    
    for (var j = 0; j < urls.length - 1; j++) {
        blobPromises.push(res[j].text());
    }
    return Promise.all(blobPromises);
}).then(function(body){
    var output = {rawData: body)};
    callback(null, output);
}).catch(callback);
```

How can this mapping be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be incorrectly assuming the then handler for `Promise.all` is invoked once for each promise. It's instead invoked once (or never if not all promises resolve) with an array containing the resolves of each promise (in the same order as their promises).

```
let promises = [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(3)];
Promises.all(promises).then(resolveObjects => 
  console.log(resolveObjects)); // [1, 2, 3]
```

For your example (modified a little, since your code has some missing vars and incorrect statements):

```
urls = ['https://example-a.com', 'https://example-b.com', 'https://example-c.com']

let promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url));

let responses = Promise.all(promises).then(responses => 
    responses.map(respnose => response.text()));
```

(Side note), an async stream dependency (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-better-stream) will allow you to treat promises of arrays or arrays of promises (or promises of arrays of promises...) more like normal arrays.

```
let responses = new Stream()
  .writePromise(...promises)
  .map(response => response.text());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't understood the array with the resolved promises would be guaranteed to be in the same order as the promises.